# Replace and RegEx issue

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I am working twitter API with LinqToTwitter API. There I am trying to format tweet text. But I have issue with replace and regex below is string which I am getting from twitter

`@TheNational: ICYMI: Louvre be first museum in Asia to show a painting http://t.co/fmp http://t.c…`

Now I am using below code replace all URL to Link for display.

First I create regex to get link

```
private readonly Regex _parseUrls = new Regex("(?<Protocol>\\w+):\\/\\/(?<Domain>[\\w@][\\w.:@]+)\\/?[\\w\\.?=%&=\\-@/$,]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Then I match them and replace as below

```
foreach (var urlMatch in _parseUrls.Matches(tweetText))
  {
    Match match = (Match)urlMatch;
    tweetText = tweetText.Replace(match.Value, string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" target=\"_blank\">{0}</a>", match.Value));
  }
```

Regex is working very good as expected but now replace is giving issue as both link in the string is starting with `http://t.co` it is replace first occurrence every time.

Somebody help me what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a proper way to do the replacement.

Use the [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) method:

```
_parseUrls.Replace(tweetText, "<a href=\"$&\" target=\"_blank\">$&</a>");
```

Or, better yet, with HTML encoding:

```
_parseUrls.Replace(tweetText,
                   match => string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" target=\"_blank\">{1}</a>",
                                          match.Value,
                                          WebUtility.HtmlEncode(match.Value))
                  );
```

This will for instance turn any `&` in the URL to `&amp;` inside the `<a>` tag. You even should encode the remaining part of the string: if someone tweets some HTML code you'd want to display it as-is instead of interpreting it.

The problem with your original approach is that the `_parseUrls.Matches(tweetText)` matches the replaced text again with each iteration.